# Rspec returns wrong Ruby Date month. Ruby's Class returns the right one

Tags: ruby, date, rspec

This is very strange? What magic am I missing?

```
class Calendar
  def initialize
    @date = Time.new
  end
  def month
    @date.strftime("%B")
  end
  def calendar
    calendar = { 'month' => self.month }
  end
end
c = Calendar.new 

puts c.calendar       => {"month"=>"February"}
```

calendar_spec.rb

```
require 'date'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'calendar'

describe Calendar do
  subject { Calendar.new }

  context "calendar" do
    it "should save current month into calendar hash" do
      expect(subject.calendar['month']).to eq(Date.new.strftime("%B"))
    end
  end

$> rspec spec
    Failures:

    1) Calendar calendar should save current month into calendar hash
     Failure/Error: expect(subject.calendar['month']).to eq(Date.new.strftime("%B"))

       expected: "January"
            got: "February"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/calendar_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.new` without arguments doesn't return today's date but:

```
Date.new
# => Mon, 01 Jan -4712
```

instead, you can use `Date.today`:

```
expect(subject.calendar['month']).to eq(Date.today.strftime("%B"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Date#new` [doesn't return today's date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new). You're using `Time.new` in your class, and `Date.new` in your test. You should probably be using `Time.now` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `Date.new` issue (it defaults to the start of the Julian period, i.e. 4712 BC), both your test and your code use the current date. This may lead to unexpected behavior when running the tests on different dates.

It's usually better to explicitly set the current time, e.g:

```
class Calendar
  def initialize(time = Time.new)
    @date = time
  end
  # ...
end
```

In your test:

```
describe Calendar do
  let(:now) { Time.new(2014, 1, 1) }
  subject { Calendar.new(now) }

  describe "#month" do
    it "returns the current month's name" do
      expect(subject.month).to eq('January')
    end
  end
  #...
end
```